How do I dynamically allocate memory for a multidimentional array in C?
Dynamically allocate memory for a multidimensional array (matrix) with a specified number of rows and columns.
How to allocate memory?
How to allocate memory for 2D array?
How to dynamically allocate memory?
I tried to use a loop to allocate memory for each row of the array.
I attempted to use another loop to allocate memory for each column of the array.
I expected the program to successfully allocate memory for the multidimensional array.
I expected the program to print the array dimensions (number of rows and columns) correctly.
I expected the program to deallocate the memory using free() without any memory leaks

You don't need to allocate memory for the columns. The columns are just the cells in the row arrays.

Welcome to SO. You forgot to tell us what you observed instead of the expected behaviour. You also forgot to show us your code. Programming is not like writing an essay. We are not interested in descriptions what you planned to implement. We need to see what you really implemented. Then we can look for mismatch between your expected behaviour and your real behaviour. For more information please read How-to-ask and edit the question to add a MCVE as well as a detailled description of observed behaviour.
